# Changing a double integral into polar coordinates $\int_0^1 \int_{2y}^2 4\cos(x^2)dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \int_{2y}^2 4\cos(x^2)dxdy$$

my try is :

$$2\int_0^1 \sqrt{\int_{2y}^2\int_{2y}^2 (e^{i(x^2+u^2)}+e^{-i(x^2+u^2)}+2)dxdu}dy$$

then changing to polar coordinates but I don't know how to change the region

always my problem in double integral is how to change the region

its self training without teacher

can any one help me in this question and this problem

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but this integral can also be done by switching order of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
\begin{align}
x&=r\cos \theta\\
y&=r\sin \theta\\
dx dy &= r dr d\theta
\end{align}
Now note that $r\cos \theta = 2$ hence $r=\frac{2}{\cos\theta}$, and that $0\leq \theta\leq\arctan\frac12$, thus
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_{2y}^y\cos x^2 dx dy &=\int_{\theta=1}^{\arctan\frac12}\int_{r=0}^{\frac{2}{\cos \theta}}\cos(r^2\cos ^2\theta)rdrd\theta\\
&=\frac12\sin(4)\int_{\theta=1}^{\arctan\frac12}\sec^2\theta d\theta\\
&=\frac{\sin(4)}{4}
\end{align}

---

[image]

Comment: sorry but i still doesn't understand how you got the new region

Comment: @user130806 I added a graph which could help visualize the integration region.